# Where can I obtain Sputnik virophage samples?

Tags: microbiology, virology

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to use virophages as viral vectors in introducing CRISPR-Cas proteins into other viruses. I was wondering where I might be able to find replication-defective Sputnik virophages or other virophages for this kind of experiment?